# filebeat is sending log directly to elastic search not to logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am facing this problem since I have deleted all indices . For that I executed the following command

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*'
```

filebeat.yml

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
     paths:
      - /var/log/syslog
    - input_type : log
      document_type: syslog
  registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]
    bulk_max_size: 1024

shipper:
logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

and logstash config files input config

```
   input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
```

and output config

```
  output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      }
    }
```

Problem is that logs are not coming through logstash , these are coming directly because I can not see new field added in kibana and in case of apche-access log there is only log as value of type.

Comment: In the future, please trim all those comments out of your config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just have a syntactical error in your Filebeat config, try changing

```
 - input_type : log
```

to

```
input_type : log
```

that `-` could definitely be messing your config up by declaring a second prospector. If all your logstash processing is done by type, then your improperly typed logs would make it to elasticsearch through logstash with no parsing done.

Comment: if I remove - then I got file loading error @will and I have already put the filters of type in logstash

Comment: hello @will thanks that was also the issue and other spacing issues in filebeat.yml now working after removing -

Answer (score -1):

As your configuration file shows ,you have commented out the elasticsearch output configuration . So , the output which you are receiving is not because of elasticsearch it must be because of logstash. You have added it as comments but this should be done:

```
elasticsearch:
# Array of hosts to connect to.
# Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 9200)
# In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:9200/path
# IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:9200
   hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

Comment: OP asked to send to logstash, specifically not straight to elastic

Comment: @WillBarnwell logstash has the configuration to output the logs into elastic search so,if logstash is not receiving any data , how come elasticsearch is recieving data ? Well what I inferred from the original question was that the user wanted to have two ouputs one through elastic search and the other through   logstash .